# Editing questions results in 404

Tags: bug, editing

I edited this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129980/bug-on-starting-ubuntu-12-04). But after saving the edit, I got a 404 page. The question was not deleted in the mean time.

Comment: this bug aafected me too :)

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce the problem. [I edited question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/129980/revisions) without problems.